# Cannot set environment variables in Chrome background.js script. Is there a way to hardcode env vars into specific files using Github Actions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

Thanks for any help the community can provide!

- **SUMMARIZED QUESTION**

  - I want to hardcode environment variables into javascript files during a build process (or something similar) depending on which GitHub branch the code is pushed to using GitHub actions.
  - There is no current build process. How can I create a build process which would accomplish this task?
  - Are there alternatives or a better approach than creating a build process? Is there some GitHub action that can transform files to accomplish the same result?
- **BACKGROUND**

  - My project is a chrome extension which scrapes a number of websites for data.
  - When the extension is loaded, a background script is specified in manifest.json

    - The background script then makes an XMLHttpRequest request to our server to get several other scripts from our server which are then activated in Chrome using eval().
    - The scripts are returned by the request responseText and parsed into JSON before being passed to the eval() function.
  - Our server is hosted on an Azure App Service.
  - We have two App Services for this project representing different environments - development and production
  - The background script specified by manifest.json looks in one of three different places for the scripts - localhost, our development server, or our production server

    - Currently we have to hardcode in this value before deploying to the App Server
- **THE PROBLEM**

  - In our background script, I would like to use an environment variable to specify the location of the scripts that changes based on which github branch/App Service the code resides on.
  - The background script and scripts retrieved by the background script cannot access environment variables set in the configuration of the App Service
  - The scripts are returned to the background script as text. All these scripts run on a local machine where the chrome extension is installed, not on the App Service.
- **SOLUTIONING**

  - I was thinking of approaching the issue in a similar manner to how I was able to specify environment variables based on branches for a React project.

    - In the Github workflow detect the branch being pushed to
    - Use env-cmd to specify a set of environment variables to use during the build process

      - https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd
    - env-cmd actually hardcodes the correct variables into the code during the build process
  - The problem with this solution is that the chrome extension does not have a build process like the React App did, so I do not have a mechanism to use env-cmd to specify the variables,

Comment: Please refer [Default GitHub Environment Variables](https://adamtheautomator.com/github-actions-environment-variables/#:~:text=%20Some%20of%20the%20paths%20you%20can%20get,unique%20number%20of%20the%20run%20command.%20More%20)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Harshitha. 

I am not trying to set an environment variable for use in a GitHub Action workflow, but rather I'm looking to set the environment variables in the actual build of my codebase through a GitHub Action workflow. I have accomplished this before in a React project using env-cmd, unfortunately my chrome extension project does not have a build process as described in the main post.

I am trying to figure out if I can create my own build process to accomplish this task or if there is an alternate solution.